# Python Django. Функция не распознает аргумент после точки

Tags: python, django, фильтр

Хотел написать фильтр в джанго, но один из аргументов не передается как аргумент.  Значение value после точки не воспринимается в качестве аргумента. Даже, pycharm, не подсвечивает value как используемую. Может есть какой-то прием для таких случаев?
Еще хочу добавить, что реализация конкретного кода для меня не критична, есть другие пути решения. Главная суть вопроса, является ли такая ситуация неразрешимой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
from django import template
from accounts.models import Profile
register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def get_profile_fields(request, value):
    field = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    return field.value
```

Comment: Ну так вы переменную `value` нигде и не используете

Comment: Вероятно вы хотели написать `return getattr(field, value)`

Comment: к сожалению, return getattr(field, value) не сработал в самом шаблоне

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, а зачем вам вообще value в аргументе?

Comment: @Даниял, чтобы в шаблоне можно было пользоваться как:  {{ request|get_profile_fields:'birth_date' }}

Answer (score 0):

```
@register.filter 
def get_profile_fields(request, value):
    field = Profile.objects.values_list(value, flat=True).get(user=request.user)
    return field
```